# ContentResolver update() for album art not working on Lollipop (works on pre-L)

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentresolver

I have a `Service` that regularly checks for missing album art and updates where necessary. It works flawlessly on **pre-Lollipop** devices but not on Lollipop.

The following snippet is from the Service.

```
private static final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("album_id", albumId);
values.put("_data", file.getAbsolutePath());
Uri newuri = this.getContentResolver().insert(sArtworkUri, values);
if (newuri == null) {
    // Failed to insert in to the database. The most likely
    // cause of this is that the item already existed in the
    // database, and the most likely cause of that is that
    // the album was scanned before, but the user deleted the
    // album art from the sd card.
    // So we try to update the row
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, Long.parseLong(albumId));
    int updatednum = this.getContentResolver().update(uri, values, null, null); //Getting error at this line on Lollipop
    if(updatednum < 1) success = false;
}
```

I'm getting the following exception at the **indicated line** on **Lollipop** devices

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id FROM album_art WHERE album_id=4
```

I've tried to find out if there have been any changes to the `MediaStore` but I've come up empty. Does anybody know why the line indicated in the snippet is failing on Lollipop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there is no such Uri in the SDK: `content://media/external/audio/albumart`

Comment: @pskink I got the Uri from the Android music player source code. I think it exists. The thing is, the code works on JB, KK devices that I tested it on.

Comment: then check it with `PackageManager#queryContentProviders` and even it exist you have no idea how long will it exist and how to use it since as i said it is not a part of official SDK

Comment: @pskink I opened the album art table using an sqlite database viewer and found that the table doesn't have any column title **_id**. There are only **album_id** and **_data** columns. I wonder why the system is trying to access a non-existent column. Btw, the uri in question seems to be in widesprrad use and for the moment I choose to continue using it. I'll make sure to watch out for any changes in the future.

Comment: Surprisingly my existing code is working on another Lollipop device that I have. It seems like the problem is device-specific but I'll leave the question open for some time, just in case anybody has a solution.

Comment: implement BaseColumns class in your pojo class which contains clolum details as:- http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem is with the `update()` method, I decided to work around the issue by avoiding using `update()` altogether. The following combination of `delete()` and `insert()` removes the need for update().

```
this.getContentResolver().delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, Long.parseLong(albumId)), null, null);
newuri = this.getContentResolver().insert(sArtworkUri, values);
```